# retrieving rows with multiple column values sqlite

Tags: android, database

In my code there is a function that fetches rows from database with specific column value. Here it is `KEY_DESC`. I also need to add the additional condition of specific value for `KEY_DATE`. How can I do that?

```
fetchEventByName()

public Cursor fetchEventByName(String inputText,String inputText1) throws SQLException {
        //Log.w(TAG, inputText);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (inputText == null || inputText.length () == 0) {
        mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_DESC, KEY_EVENT, KEY_DATE },
        null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        else {
        mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_DESC, KEY_EVENT, KEY_DATE},
                KEY_DESC + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
        null, null, null, null);

        }
        if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_DESC, KEY_EVENT, KEY_DATE},
                KEY_DESC + " like '%" + inputText + "%' or "+KEY_DATE+"="+WHAT_EVER, null,
        null, null, null, null);
```